# How to hide wifi errors on boot (Kubuntu)?

Tags: boot, networking, kubuntu, kde

last week the inbuilt WiFi card of my dell laptop broke. I tried everything with drivers but it didn't fix, so I went to the store and got a USB WiFi dongle. I am able to connect to networks now but when the pc boots it shows a ton of "iwifi initiation failed" errors and then shows the plasma logo and continues normally. How do I hide these errors or tell kubuntu not to use the inbuilt one at all?

Comment: Just asking: wouldn't it be easier or more efficient to just remove the WiFi card from the laptop (assuming it isn't buried under 100 screws and plastic covers)? You can easily replace it (you don't *have* to, and Kubuntu will ignore the WiFi card port if it is empty).

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt, that was my first thought but it is unreachable after opening the back panel because of a plastic lid kind of thing. I can only reach the ram and hdd easily.

Comment: then I imagine it wasn't exposed through covers intentionally, and you'd have to dig right down to the motherboard itself to remove. That is kind of silly but yeah I understand why you don't just remove it. A lot of hassle for a tiny little card.